# Python - List of dictionary to list of list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this kind of list of dictionary

```
[
  {'word': u'live', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 1L},
  {'word': u'school', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 1L},
  {'word': u'job', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 2L},
  {'word': u'house', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 2L},
]
```

That I'd like to transform into this kind of list of list of dictionary

```
[
  [
    {'word': u'live', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 1L}
    {'word': u'school', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 1L},
  ],
  [
    {'word': u'job', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 2L},
    {'word': u'house', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 2L},
  ],
]
```

Based on the key `part` and ordered on `sequence`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can be confusing, here's how you can do it:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [
...   {'word': u'live', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 1L},
...   {'word': u'school', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 1L},
...   {'word': u'job', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 2L},
...   {'word': u'house', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 2L},
... ]

>>> l2 = [sorted(list(g), key=lambda x:x["sequence"])
...       for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x["part"])]

>>> pprint.pprint(l2)
[[{'part': 1L, 'sequence': 1L, 'word': u'live'},
  {'part': 1L, 'sequence': 2L, 'word': u'school'}],
 [{'part': 2L, 'sequence': 1L, 'word': u'job'},
  {'part': 2L, 'sequence': 2L, 'word': u'house'}]]
```

This assumes that `l` is already sorted by the `part` key, if not, use

```
>>> l2 = [sorted(list(g), key=lambda x:x["sequence"])
...       for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x:x["part"]), 
...                                     key=lambda x:x["part"])]
```

Comment: Indeed itertools is confusing for me, thank you for your bit of code

Comment: I'd sort on both `part` and `sequence` first (with `operator.itemgetter()`), in case the records are out of order.

Comment: @Tim pietzcker, How to do grouping by considering both "sequence" & "part" instead of considering "part" key alone?

Comment: @MahamuthaM: So one group for each permutation of sequence and part?

Comment: @Time pietzcker, Yes

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` (or `list.sort()`) and [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response but I am unable to decipher how intertools works (I have just started to code in Phyton/Django)

Answer (score 1):

Group the parts using a dictionary:

```
import collections

dictlist = [
  {'word': u'live', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 1L},
  {'word': u'school', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 1L},
  {'word': u'job', 'sequence': 1L, 'part': 2L},
  {'word': u'house', 'sequence': 2L, 'part': 2L},
]

dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in dictlist:
    dd[d['part']].append(d)
dd.values()
```

To ordered by sequence, just used sorted with a sort key specified:

```
[sorted(dd[k], key=lambda x: x['sequence']) for k in dd]
```

Overall, this produces:

```
[[{'part': 1L, 'sequence': 1L, 'word': u'live'},
  {'part': 1L, 'sequence': 2L, 'word': u'school'}],
 [{'part': 2L, 'sequence': 1L, 'word': u'job'},
  {'part': 2L, 'sequence': 2L, 'word': u'house'}]]
```

Comment: itertools seems to be quite powerful